# Return multiple lists from dictionary keys using for lops

Tags: python, loops

I am having a issue seperating data from a dictionairy into different lists:

Depending on the input given by the user, my code outputs a given dictionary. The dictionary keys depend on the input meaning that I never have the same keys.

Assume that one of the outputs is the following:

```
data = {'A': [[a,1],[a,2],[a,3]], 'B': [[b,1],[b,2],[b,3],[b,4]], 'C': [[c,1],[c,2],[c,3],[c,4],[c,5]]}
```

I would like to use the for loop in order to give a new variable the list of the key:

So far, the closest I have been able to achieve is the following:

```
number_of_types = []

for i in data:
    number_of_types += i
    # I can not find a way to store the values of the key 'A' in a variable, then have a different variable for B. The issue is that I do not always have the same amount of keys. I might have a dictionary with 4 or 5 different keys
```

I am sorry if this is out of context, I am relatively new to StackOverflow and it seems like people do not appreciate some questions. If this is not supposed to be here please let me know and help me understand why it is not the place for it. Once again I apologize for any inconvenience. Thank you for the help

Comment: Apologies, I have fixed it. It is a transcription error, not one in my code.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what is your expected output? Also see: `list(data.keys())`, `list(data.values())`, `list(data.items())`

Comment: You don't need to create different variable names. Just use the dictionary keys as they are.

Comment: `data[i]` is the value of the key in the loop.

Comment: `a,b,c` etc are all variable names - did you mean to use strings?

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to separate the data of each key into its own list.

Comment: a, b, c = *data.values() ? Assuming you only have 3 values

Comment: By separating them into lists, I could use the itertools function product in order to find all possible combinations. the product functions only takes list inputs

Comment: `for i in data:  bbb = data[i]` ? but whatfor do you need bbb - you can as well use `data[i]` instead. `for i in data:` iterates all keys that are inside your dictionary. It seems as if you would profit from knowledge of datastructures - you find that here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Yes patrick, I have tried yout method, but the variable bbb keeps the last occurence of i in data.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help !